# Button in relative layout pushed off screen by TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layouts for some parts of my app, made up of a checkbox, a button, some text, and another button (please see first screenshot, ex: [5min] after screen off [except]).

The problem is for other languages, the text to the left of the last button could be much longer, pushing the "except" button slightly or completely off screen. How else could I do this so that the button (along with the text) wrap around to the next line? Right now only the text does. Here is the code:

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_after_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_set_time_turn_off"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_data_check_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_set_time_turn_off"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_set_time_turn_off"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:text="@string/text_disable_after_time" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_set_disable_exceptions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_data_check_minutes"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView_data_check_minutes"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/button_disable_except"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Normal layout:

[image: Normal layout]

"except" button pushed off screen:

[image: "except" button pushed off screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap these in a `LinearLayout` instead since, after all, they are just linear. Then position the `LinearLayout` how you need to according to your needs.

This will allow you to make use of `layout_weight` which will make sure that each `View` only takes up as much space as needed. You would need to play with the `weights` to get what you want but something like 1|2|1 looks close to what you want.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_after_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_set_time_turn_off"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_data_check_minutes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:text="@string/text_disable_after_time" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_set_disable_exceptions"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/button_disable_except"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that I made the `width` of each `"0dp"` because you typically need that when using `weight` for a horizontal layout. I also replaced the `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` with `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to match the corresponding attributes of `LinearLayout`. I also removed the `to_right_of` and such attributes as those are no longer needed with a `LinearLayout`.

I haven't tested it but this should get you close.

[LinearLayout docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:gravity)

Another option may be to use the [maxWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxWidth) property of `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @codeMagic . It doesn't do exactly what I wanted, which was to push the text AND button to the next line, but it does work. The textView becomes multiple lines and the buttons remain in their place. I had to make the weights of the buttons 0.00000001 and the weight of the textView 1, otherwise the buttons were getting squished. I'm not sure why the weights seem backward. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone can think of a way for the text and last button to wrap to the next line, otherwise I will mark this as correct.

Comment: Actually even better, I set the weight of the inner textView to 1, and set no weight on the buttons (default is 0), but use wrap_content for the widths on the buttons and it works perfectly!